# How to detect 16550 UART chip in MS-DOS x86 Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, serial-port, x86-16, dos, uart

I am trying to work out how to write code in MS-DOS assembly to detect if 16550 UART chip (serial controller) is installed, or if there is a generic method to detect the model of UART chip installed.

So far I have checked the following resources:

- Advanced MS-DOS Programming Second Edition
- Writing MS-DOS Device
  Drivers
- Ralf Brown's Interrupt List (Although it may be in here I have tried searching it for serial and 16550 and haven't found it)
- Have searched through DosBox source code for clues as I know it has implemented this but couldn't find where
- https://wiki.osdev.org/Serial_Ports

Have been unable to find a copy yet of 16550 programming manual for MS-DOS.
I have no problem initializing serial port, sending/receiving data to it, the challenge is how to detect the specific chip or at least confirm if chip is 16550 model.

Comment: This may help: [The Serial Port rel. 14](http://www.sci.muni.cz/docs/pc/serport.txt)

Comment: If you limit yourself to emulated DOS, only four addresses have ever been used for serial ports. The UARTs have a scratchpad register you can use to test their presence. [OSDev does a good job recapping it all](https://wiki.osdev.org/Serial_Ports).

Comment: Yes I have no problem getting that far, and know about these addresses. The problem is detecting the UART CHIP type is 16550 as other models are possible. There are applications that do this such as "LapLink" which shows type chip type used for serial port.

Comment: Serial ports on modern PCs can be enumerated using ACPI (for ones on the motherboard) or PCI PnP (for ones in PCI-Express or PCI cards).

Comment: not sure why this is closed "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries" As I'm not asking for any of that...??? I just reference I had checked those before asking the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not in assembler, this can be converted to assembler. In C from http://www.sci.muni.cz/docs/pc/serport.txt

```
int detect_UART(unsigned baseaddr)
{
   // this function returns 0 if no UART is installed.
   // 1: 8250, 2: 16450 or 8250 with scratch reg., 3: 16550, 4: 16550A
   int x,olddata;

   // check if a UART is present anyway
   olddata=inp(baseaddr+4);
   outp(baseaddr+4,0x10);
   if ((inp(baseaddr+6)&0xf0)) return 0;
   outp(baseaddr+4,0x1f);
   if ((inp(baseaddr+6)&0xf0)!=0xf0) return 0;
   outp(baseaddr+4,olddata);
   // next thing to do is look for the scratch register
   olddata=inp(baseaddr+7);
   outp(baseaddr+7,0x55);
   if (inp(baseaddr+7)!=0x55) return 1;
   outp(baseaddr+7,0xAA);
   if (inp(baseaddr+7)!=0xAA) return 1;
   outp(baseaddr+7,olddata); // we don't need to restore it if it's not there
   // then check if there's a FIFO
   outp(baseaddr+2,1);
   x=inp(baseaddr+2);
   // some old-fashioned software relies on this!
   outp(baseaddr+2,0x0);
   if ((x&0x80)==0) return 2;
   if ((x&0x40)==0) return 3;
   return 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The procedure above (from serport.txt doc) doesn't work properly (at least not everywhere, so it's not reliable).
Find a file uartty12.zip on simtel.net mirror (section io_utils), that contains binary and asm source of proper detection procedure.